# Does a mining reward transaction have a hash?

Tags: transactions, mining, hash, coinbase, reward

I can't find a mining reward transaction hash for a given block. I can see the block hash, all the transactions inside the block, etc. But the mining reward transaction is not listed among the details.

Does a mining reward transaction have a hash? Does it have inputs and outputs? I tried different block explorer sites and JavaScript web3 functions. What kind of transaction is a mining reward? How is it implemented?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no inputs and outputs in Ethereum, just state changes and balances. Therefore, mining rewards don't have a transaction hash since they are not a transaction.

Each block contains the miner's address, and when the block is published, the miner just gets 5 more Ether added to their balance, without the need for a transaction.

See [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/326/131) for more about UTXOs vs Balances

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the code increasing miner's balance with reward amount without any TX being created: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/v1.9.10/consensus/ethash/consensus.go#L638