# Where can you find the block's coinbase transaction using web3js?

Tags: web3js

I have noticed that the coinbase award for the block is not contained in the list of transactions retuned by e.g web3.eth.getBlock. Nor is it contained in its own field. I cannot even find an incoming transaction on the miners account on etherscan.  I need to be able to look up each blocks coinbase award- any ideas how to do this using web3.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [Tjaden link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/does-a-mining-reward-transaction-have-a-hash), no transaction is created for the miner reward. Instead, the balance of the account in `block.miner` address is increased.

I'm not sure your use case but if you want to calculate the reward amount the miner received in it's account, the formula is stated in [Yellow Paper](http://paper.gavwood.com/) eq 148:

`5 ETH  * (1 + block.uncles.length / 32)`

Notes:

- There are also some ETH sent to uncles, not sure if you need that too
- Be careful when doing math operations, checkout https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#a-note-on-big-numbers-in-web3js