# State transition model

Tags: balances, hash

It is known that Ethereum follows State transition model. How is the balance of each account known at any given time ? From my understanding, the yellow paper states that the balance is not stored on blockchain, where is it stored and how is it modified?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15042/how-are-ether-balances-stored-on-the-ethereum-blockchain