# Is it possible to have multiple address in the same account?

Tags: addresses, payments, storj

I mean : getting several payments from several addresses to the same account so I could send all the coins at once and not paying the fee for each transaction

I'm willing to run `ETH` Node if necessary

P.S. if you need to know why , it's because of storj payment rules that requires to have different address for each Storj Node in order to get the minimum payment [1.5 $]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i mean : getting several payments from several addresses to the same account so i could send all the coins at once and not paying the fee for each transaction

No, because of Ethereum's account-based system, there's no way to do this in Ethereum like there is in Bitcoin. You'll have to send the contents of each of your addresses to one main address.

(See: [What are the pros and cons of Ethereum balances vs. UTXOs?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/326/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-ethereum-balances-vs-utxos))

Remember, if you're just sending between your own accounts you could set a very low gas price and let it run overnight. (Having said that, even transactions of 1 Gwei are currently being confirmed in an average time of [3.2 minutes](https://ethgasstation.info/).)

Comment: if i'm running an eth node can i set my own gas limit becouse MyEtherWallet requires minimum gas of 210,000 for tokens

Comment: That's the amount of gas, not the gas price. Set the price as low as it will go.

Comment: how to set the price ? , i thought the price is changed automatically based on the network status

Comment: You can (should be able to) set the price to anything you like. The miners will decide if they want to take your transaction or not. If you have time to wait, then even if you set a very low price, the miners will take it eventually. There should be a slider somewhere in MEW to change the price. (As far as I can remember - I haven't used it in a while.) See: https://myetherwallet.github.io/knowledge-base/gas/what-is-gas-ethereum.html