# How do you get the UTXOs a transaction is spending using web3.js?

Tags: web3js, transactions, blockchain

I'm unsure how to get the UTXOs that a transaction is spending.

Here's what I have so far. I get transaction details from txhash

```
web3.eth.getTransaction("0x97df3cd87f87bb6f04e643b66f495e993e9c128632549c539c76caf1ca8d1e2a").then(function(receipt){
  console.log(receipt);
});
```

It provides

```
blockHash:"0x13c008fbe05e6a181cdecdc434d1a0dd089918cd71861650131e00a69997dbe9"
blockNumber:6810576
from:"0xF092966e7bcc2b5646e0F0c20A715584DB37cd4B"
gas:600000
gasPrice:"20000000000"
hash:"0x97df3cd87f87bb6f04e643b66f495e993e9c128632549c539c76caf1ca8d1e2a"
input:"0x"
nonce:1135
r:"0x47397afae235efb00910e69da29ff30177ecf227619c09cdb50af880d24c20ea"
s:"0x7df404ca4bec847e45ec3934e5b8047136a9a5207d9801795d5d05673105a7c6"
to:"0xb60fdD0914b966b38EcFeFB9cb98C86F920EC7f6"
transactionIndex:4
v:"0x1c"
value:"3000000000000000"
```

This has the from address and the value, but what are the UTXOs that the value is coming from?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking. Can you give an explicit example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi , i updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ethereum, there is nothing like inputs or outputs as in Bitcoin. It doesn't work on the concept of UTXO. To know the address from which amount is deducted, check the `from` field of a transaction.
In that particular transaction, you cannot know that the Ether that you are spending, is received from where. But as a whole you can know about all of your incoming and outgoing transactions.

See explorer: https://etherscan.io/

For more, see this: [What are the pros and cons of Ethereum balances vs. UTXOs?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/326/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-ethereum-balances-vs-utxos)

Comment: A.K you mean we not able to get the transactions of how current transaction amount came to our account. Am i correct ? is my understanding correct ?

Comment: the field `from` tells you from which account the ether is coming.

Comment: @SammuSundar i have updated the answer

Comment: Thanks @A.K. Now i understand the transaction in ethereum. Is it possible to get recent input transaction of the account

Comment: Yes, you can get the list of all transactions and filter the input transaction. Also if it answers your question, mark it correct answer

Comment: Thank @A.K. your answer is much useful .The following one is part of different I cant find any function to get the transactions of account in web3. getTransactionCount(account) provide total count.but not able to find the function to get the transaction .

Comment: @SammuSundar See this: https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts

Comment: @A.K. etherscan API is useful . is etherscan api is free ? . they didn't mention in that api page.